# IF/CASE condition for SQL Query before Join Statement

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a query which performs an INNER JOIN on an other table. I have a situation where if I have a variable set then the same query should be doing a LEFT JOIN instead.

So apart from writing the same query twise in If and Else is there any better way to achieve this?

Ex:

```
    MERGE XXX
      USING (SELECT a,b,c
        FROM #temp1 p
        INNER JOIN #temp2 s on p.SlmID = s.SlmID
        ) AS source
      ON (1=0)
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (x,y,z
    )
        VALUES (p,q,r
    )
      OUTPUT source.a, INSERTED.x
        INTO #temp1 (a, x);
```

So If I have a variable @PoNum set, I should replace INNER JOIN with LEFT JOIN.

Help Appreciated!!

Thank you

Comment: Do you know the different between `mysql` and `sql-server`? Why did you add these tags for question? Do you use the both?

Comment: Please tag properly.  The syntax is different between `mysql` and `sql-server`.  Also it is useless if help you, but on the wrong system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, I used the full outer join and control it by the where condition.

```
MERGE XXX
      USING (SELECT a,b,c
        FROM #temp1 p
        Full OUTER JOIN #temp2 s on p.SlmID = s.SlmID
        Where (@PoNum=0 AND p.SlmID is not null and s.SlmID is not null)
           OR (@PoNum=1 AND p.SlmID is not null) --Variable Set, Left Join
        ) AS source
      ON (1=0)
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (x,y,z
    )
        VALUES (p,q,r
    )
      OUTPUT source.a, INSERTED.x
        INTO #temp1 (a, x);
```

Comment: Thank you, This was very helpful and worked for my case.